# Set app to use UTC globally

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, utc

How can I for an IOS app from code default to use UTC as the default timezone.
In other words, if anywhere from my app I initialize an NSDate, I want to it to be using UTC as the timezone. I don't want to have to specify a timezone for every NSdate object created.

I also do not want to change any preferences on the device.

Answer (score 0):

You **do not specify** time zone for `NSDate`. It is just point on the time line.

> NSDate objects represent a single point in time. Date objects (...)
>   represent an invariant point in time. - [NSDate Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

You have to take care of presenting the date. So set a desired time zone for the `NSDateFormatter` when you create a string representation of a date. This is when you specify the time zone.

Answer (score 0):

I think Making a Category of `NSDate` would be best. And use the category where ever needed

something like

.h fille

```
@interface NSDate (UTCDate)

+(NSDate *) UTCTDateForLocalDate:(NSDate *)localDate;
@end
```

.m file

```
@implementation NSDate (UTCDate)

+(NSDate *) UTCTDateForLocalDate:(NSDate *)localDate{

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZ"];
    NSString *localDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:localDate];
    NSTimeZone *timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"];
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:timeZone];
    NSDate *UTCDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:localDateString];

    return UTCDate;
}



@end
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I ended up solving it:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    //default app to use UTC
    [NSTimeZone setDefaultTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"]];
}
```